# mysql table tables_priv index is corrupted and the best possible way to repair it

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, errors, corruption

I am using MySQL with XAMPP.

For sometime now I keep getting a server unavailable error and upon digging deeper I noticed that my `mysql.tables_priv` table index is corrupted (ARIA Database Type). I have tried running `aria_chk` and `myisamchk` to repair, but to no avail. I have also tried `mysql_upgrade` but again this didn't help.

The only thing I can think of now is to manually remove the `tables_priv.MAD` file from `xampp\mysql\data\mysql` folder, create an empty one and `REPAIR TABLE tables_priv`.

Can you kindly advise if that is the right and safe approach to take?

Also, if you have any other suggestion then please do mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is `mysql.tables_priv` in MariaDB 10.3

```
MariaDB [information_schema]> show create table mysql.tables_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tables_priv
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tables_priv` (
  `Host` char(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Table_name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Grantor` char(141) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `Table_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','Delete','Create','Drop','Grant','References','Index','Alter','Create View','Show view','Trigger','Delete versioning rows') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Column_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','References') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Table_name`),
  KEY `Grantor` (`Grantor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Table privileges'
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [information_schema]> select version();
+----------------------------------+
| version()                        |
+----------------------------------+
| 10.3.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [information_schema]>
```

You could do the following

```
USE mysql
CREATE TABLE `tables_priv_new` (
  `Host` char(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Table_name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Grantor` char(141) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `Table_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','Delete','Create','Drop','Grant','References','Index','Alter','Create View','Show view','Trigger','Delete versioning rows') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Column_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','References') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Table_name`),
  KEY `Grantor` (`Grantor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; ## or use Aria if that works for you
INSERT INTO tables_priv_new SELECT * FROM tables_priv;
FLUSH TABLES tables_priv,tables_priv_new;
RENAME TABLE
    tables_priv TO tables_priv_old
   ,tables_priv_new TO tables_priv
;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the corrupted index in the `tables_priv` table manually, consider the following steps: stop MySQL, and remove `tables_priv.MAD`, start MySQL, and run `REPAIR TABLE mysql.tables_priv;`. Verify with `CHECK TABLE mysql.tables_priv;` before restarting MySQL.

However, if it does not work, you can try this Stellar MySQL repair tool, see if you can see everything in the demo preview.
Let me know if it works.